# Raffle probability with multiple draws

Tags: probability

> I have $x$ tickets for a raffle, and $y$ total tickets have been issued. Every 5 minutes, 5 tickets are drawn and awarded, then the tickets are re-entered into the raffle. So for every draw I will have $x$, and $y$ total tickets.
>   How can I determine what my expected number of prizes would be if these draws continued every 5 minutes for 30 days?

Comment: You should also mention what you have attempted on this question, and where you are stuck

Comment: Hint: figure out your expected number of prizes for a single draw. Then since each draw is independent, multiply this expected value by the number of draws over the 30 day period.

Comment: Note: The Independence isn't actually important for this. The Linearity of Expectation does not require it.  What is useful to know is that each draw has an *identical distribution*.

Comment: I know how to determine the odds of winning nothing (and the odds of winning at least once) for a single draw, or for all 8640 draws.

But I don't know how to determine the expected number of prizes I would win from a single draw.

Comment: The best I can come up with is each ticket is worth 1/y prizes.  And since I have x tickets, my expected value from 1 raffle is x(1/y)*5=z, and so z*8640 is my expected value for all raffles.  But I believe this is incorrect, because it doesn't factor in how odds change after each consecutive ticket is drawn.